Elleptic equation with boundary condition infinity?
Let $ c \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d) $, $ f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d) $, and $ a_{i,j} \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d) $. We denote $ A = [a_{i,j}] $.
Now consider the problem:
$$
\operatorname{div}(A(x) \nabla u) + c(x) u = f \quad \text{in } \mathbb{R}^d
$$
$$
u(x) \underset{|x| \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
$$
The question I have is: how can I find the weak formulation of this problem? In fact, I have set
$$
V = \{ u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^d) \mid u(x) \underset{|x| \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 \}
$$
and then I am trying to prove that the weak formulation is
$$
\int A(x) \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dx + \int c u v \, dx = \int f v \, dx \quad \forall v \in V.
$$
However, the problem, in my opinion, is that to arrive at this step, I first need $ V $ to be a Hilbert space, and that the space of test functions $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d) $ is dense in $ V $. In order to apply this density to obtain the weak formulation, I cannot prove these two steps. Do you have any ideas on how to proceed with this kind of boundary condition?

Imho you can forget about this condition. It is somehow already encoded in the integrability requirement $u \in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$.

$C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $V$ becasue it is dense in the superset $H^1 (\mathbb{R}^d) = H^1_0 (\mathbb{R}^d)$

But here we want to show V is closed ??

You are right that this is indeed an issue: A Sobolev function in dimension $n \geq 2$ does not necessarily have to vanish at infinity, see this question: Must continuous $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ function tend to zero at infinity?
So in your case, we just take the this $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ from the linked question und consider cut-offs $u_k$ of it. However, we see that $u_k \in V$, but its limit in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is not. Hence $V$ is not closed.
In my opinion, you want to use is the following:
The space of continuous functions
$$
V_0=\{u \in C^{0}(\mathbb{R}^n) \mid \lim_{|x| \to \infty} u(x)=0 \}
$$
is a Banach space with $\sup$ norm. What I would recommend is to find a weak solution in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ first, then use elliptic regularity to show that $u \in H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $s > \frac{n}{2}$. This then implies that $u \in V_0$ and $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset V_0$ is a closed subspace. A very elegant and quick proof of this fact can be found in this question.
